# How to make background-color circular on a span text

Tags: html, css

I have a spanned text `1` with background color red. I want to make the background color round which will enclose the spanned text `1`. But what i have at the moment isn't doing the trick.

How can i get this done?

```css
.text-span{
  background:red;
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-span">1</span><span>info</span>
```

Comment: I would recommend you create a code snippet example for this question so people will be able to easier answer your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to display it inline-block. This allows you to manipulate its size.

Then, you need to give him the same height, same width to make it square.

After that, you will make a border radius of 50% so that it becomes round.

Finally, you can center it by giving it the line-height of the height, and center aligning the text.

And voilà !

```css
.text-span{
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-span">1</span><span>info</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```css
.text-span{
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-span">1</span><span>info</span>
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't absolutely center the content inside the circle using just the padding. I suggest you this snippet to center anything inside it with a simple snippet.

This solution have just a note, you need to set the circle size big enough or crop the content with the `text-overflow` property.

```css
.text-span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-span::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text-span" data-content="1"></span>
  info
</div>


<div>
  <span class="text-span" data-content="99"></span>
  info
</div>
```